# Is it possible to split this mysql column result into multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the fields `composer`, and `play_count`. I have made this query for showing the sum of `play_count` for each composer:

```
select composer, sum(play_count) as total_plays
from tracks
group by composer
order by total_plays desc
```

Result:

```
composer    total_plays
Bar Fooson  1765
Foo Barson  586
Foo Barson, Bar Fooson  397
```

Would it be possible to split the composer field using `,`  as a divider, so that the result is:

```
composer    total_plays
Bar Fooson  2162
Foo Barson  983
```

instead?

I have attempted multiple things but have not gotten close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best not to store multiple values in a single column.  If you know you have at most two values, you can use:

```
select composer, sum(play_count) as total_plays
from ((select substring_index(composer, ',', 1) as composer, play_count
       from tracks
      ) union all
      (select substring_index(composer, ',', -1) as composer, play_count
       from tracks
       where composer like '%,%'
      )
     ) ct
group by composer
order by total_plays desc;
```

If you can have more than two items in the list, then you can add additional conditions to the subquery to get the additional elements.

That said, you should probably put your effort into fixing your data model.  It sounds like you want a `trackComposers` table to keep track of *all* composers for a given track.

EDIT:

If you had a maximum of three composers, you would use:

```
((select substring_index(composer, ',', 1) as composer, play_count
  from tracks
 ) union all
 (select substring_index(substring_index(composer, ',', 2), ',', -1) as composer, play_count
  from tracks
  where composer like '%,%'
 ) union all
 (select substring_index(substring_index(composer, ',', 3), ',', -1) as composer, play_count
  from tracks
  where composer like '%,%,%'
 )
)
```

More composers would continue the logic.

Comment: Works great, thank you. Yes, this is terrible database design, because it's directly imported from an iTunes library XML where there is only one field for composers.

Comment: If there can be any amount of composers, would I just add another union all with       `(select substring_index(composer, ',', -2) as composer, play_count`, `(select substring_index(composer, ',', -3 as composer, play_count` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a general solution and would work in MYSQL v8 and beyond. In this solution you can have as many comma separated values in the column composer. The query logic would dynamically handle it and no edit is required in the query (like - adding union and stuff like that)

```
WITH RECURSIVE sequence AS (
    SELECT 1 AS level
    UNION ALL
    SELECT level + 1 AS value
    FROM sequence
    WHERE sequence.level < (Select max(length(composer) - length(REPLACE(composer, ',', '')))+1 from tracks) 
)

SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.composer, ',', j.whichval), ',', -1)) as exploded, Sum(Playcount)
    FROM tracks table1 
     JOIN 
     (SELECT level As whichval
        FROM sequence) as j
    WHERE 1 
     AND j.whichval<= 1+LENGTH(table1.composer) - LENGTH(REPLACE(table1.composer,',',''))
     group by TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.composer, ',', j.whichval), ',', -1));
```

The key logic of the query above is to generate rows using a recursive CTE. And the number of rows generated depends on the max number of separators + 1 (comma in this case)  - which translates to maximum possible values in the list - taking into consideration the values across all the records of the column composer. In this way it avoids the manual intervention of adding unions manually in the query depending on how long the list can be.

Here is a db fiddle link to illustrate - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a036adb690a124cb936bcef472062f0

Comment: @DisplayName - If I may ask, which version of MySQL you are using?